# How can I put the title of the website into an array that refers to the respective website?

Tags: php, html

I use the [RollingCurl.php](https://github.com/joshfraser/rolling-curl/blob/master/RollingCurl.php) from Josh Fraser

At the moment in the array is the `<title>` Tag from all websites. But not related to the right Website, the sequence is every time different, because of the loading Speed of each Website.

```
<?php

$array = [];

// a little example that fetches a bunch of sites in parallel and echos the page title and response info for each request
function request_callback($response, $info) {
    global $array;

    // parse the page title out of the returned HTML
    if (preg_match("~<title>(.*?)</title>~i", $response, $out)) {
        $array[] = $out[1];
    }
}

require("RollingCurl.php");

// top 20 sites according to alexa (11/5/09)
$urls = array("http://www.google.com",
              "http://www.facebook.com",
              "http://www.yahoo.com",
              "http://www.youtube.com",
              "http://www.live.com",
              "http://www.wikipedia.com",
              "http://www.blogger.com",
              "http://www.msn.com",
              "http://www.baidu.com",
              "http://www.yahoo.co.jp",
              "http://www.myspace.com",
              "http://www.qq.com",
              "http://www.google.co.in",
              "http://www.twitter.com",
              "http://www.google.de",
              "http://www.microsoft.com",
              "http://www.google.cn",
              "http://www.sina.com.cn",
              "http://www.wordpress.com",
              "http://www.google.co.uk");
$rc = new RollingCurl("request_callback");
$rc->window_size = 20;
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $request = new RollingCurlRequest($url);
    $rc->add($request);
}
$rc->execute();

var_dump($array);
?>
```

Comment: What's the actual issue? If you just want it in an array, then create an array and inside the callback, add to it. You might need to `global` the array.

Comment: Get rid of the `echo $array` and add `$array = [];` before the function so it's defined.

Comment: I have tried this: `function request_callback($response, $info) {
global $array;
 if (preg_match("~<title>(.*?)</title>~i", $response, $out)) {
  $array[] = $out[1];
 }
  echo $array[1];
}`

Comment: Why do you keep adding `echo` if you just want the array? Did you add the `$array` assignment before the function definition? Is something wrong with your new code? You're not actually telling me anything.

Comment: @Jonnix The new code doesn't work well, it will output multiple times the same <title> of a website.
`global $array;` before the function also not working.

The `echo` is only for me the feedback, to see is the array working or not.

This is what I want:

`echo $array[0];` -> output: <title> from website 1
`echo $array[1];` -> output: <title> from website 2
`echo $array[2];` -> output: <title> from website 3
...

Comment: Just tried https://pastebin.com/HDiCvrtw and it seems to work fine. Gets an array of titles.

Comment: As a side note, I don't usually suggest using globals. A different option to stop using them might have been to use an anonymous function with a `use`.

Comment: Ok thx, now it‘s work with your Code.

Comment: But the values from the array not every time in the same Position. And I can not say which title belongs to which website

Comment: Looking at the RollingCurl code, the third param to the callback function should be the request it relates to. No idea if it does any sorting.

Comment: You could use an associative array using url as a key, instead of just appending results to the global array as they come. $array["$url" ] = $out[1];

Comment: @Truckbros: Do you can give me an Exempel or can you implemented in my Code?